# Where does the Rust macOS pkg installer install to?

Tags: macos, rust

I want to try the Eclipse-based Rust IDE [RustDT](https://github.com/RustDT/RustDT) and it asks for the Rust installation and source directories. I assume the source directory is relative to the installation directory, but I have no clue where it is installed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Rust executable binaries (`rustc`, `cargo`, `rustdoc`) are installed to `/usr/local/bin` by default with the macOS installer. Rust libraries are installed to `/usr/local/lib/rustlib/`.

To use RustDT, you should install Racer [following the instructions from the repository](https://github.com/phildawes/racer).

After Racer is installed, you should configure the path to `rustc`, `racer`, and the source files for Rust in the RustDT preferences.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure of this, but I think you need to clone the source seperately. RustDT uses racer (I think) which needs uncompiled source code.

Cloning [this branch on github](http://github.com/rust-lang/rust/tree/stable) and pointing to it should do the trick. No need to build.

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer is outdated. As of 9/29/2017 the following works for RustDT on a MacBook Pro running Sierra and using Eclipse Neon.

Install the configuration tools [per this guide](https://github.com/RustDT/RustDT/blob/latest/documentation/UserGuide.md#configuration). As you install each package, the last line of output before your terminal exits the process is the directory you need to use for the Rust preferences in RustDT. Take note of these.

(I used the nightly build installer because there was a compiler error when installing 'Racer'. Your experience may vary.)

In the Rust preferences, configure as follows and Eclipse will let you know if you're wrong. If you took notes on your installation locations you should be fine. Note: I've blotted out my username on my computer because it's a work machine. It's `/Users/your_username/path`

[image]